# Creating a new column based on different if conditions in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column which contains text:

```
         A
"Books Car Animals" 
"Jet Transport Fuel"
"Dell Acer Lenovo"
```

and so on. I need to create a new column based on conditions that if the text in cell contains Books assign it fist, if it contains Dell assign it second and if it contains Fuel assign it third. The final table should look like this:

```
         A                          B
"Books Car Animals"               First
"Jet Transport Fuel"              Third
"Dell Acer Lenovo"                Second
```

I am having trouble assigning multiple if in the same formula. Any leads on this is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Books",A1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Dell",A1)),IF(ISERROR(FIND("Fuel",A1)),"None","Third"),"Second"),"First")
```

If none of the words are in the cell this will write `None`.